# multiple textboxes for one field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

If I have 3 text boxes for 3 field which need to be appended together, how would you go about doing this?

for example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { @id = "PhoneNumber1"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { @id = "PhoneNumber2"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { @id = "PhoneNumber3"})
```

but when I call model.PhoneNumber in the controller, I only get the first text box value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need multiple phone numbers in your model `phoneNumber1, phoneNumber2, phoneNumber3` as you can only bind one element of one type to the model.

Alternatively you can use FormCollection

use standard imports instead of model binding

```
<input type="text" value="" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber1" />
<input type="text" value="" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber2" />
<input type="text" value="" name="phoneNumber" id="phoneNumber3" />
```

**Then in your Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model, FormCollection frm){

//get elements from form
String[] numbers = frm["phoneNumber"].Split(',');

// you will have your 3 numbers


}
```

Comment: Hmm, I think I may go with the second option. As it's actually just one phone number, I just had to separate it in 3 textboxes for area code, and such

Answer (score -2):

Javascript hack:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#formID').submit(function() {
    $('#PhoneNumber1').val($('#PhoneNumber1').val() + ', ' + $('#PhoneNumber2').val() + ', ' + $('#PhoneNumber2').val());
});

</script>
```